# How do I return several collections with only one specific key pair?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Using lodash, I want to take multiple collections with multiple key pairs and return the collections with a specific key pair.

input JSON:

```
var rawCollection = [
{
    "city": "Antwerp",
    "region": "Europe",
    "spanish_city_name": "Amberes",
    "title": "Antwerp"
},
{
    "city": "Antwerp",
    "region": "NA",
    "spanish_city_name": "Amberes",
    "title": "Antwerp"
},
{
    "city": "Antwerp",
    "region": "SA",
    "spanish_city_name": "Amberes",
    "title": "Antwerp"
}
```

]

desired output:

```
[{                     
    "region": "Europe",
},
{
    "region": "NA",
},
{
    "region": "SA"
}]
```

I have tried `_uniq(rawCollection, 'region')`, `_filter` and several other functions

Answer (score 3):

Use [`_.pluck`](http://lodash.com/docs#pluck):

```
var regions = _.pluck(rawCollection , 'region');
```

This will give you an array of regions names (an array of strings) rather than an array of *objects*. Like this:

```
[ 'Europe', 'NA', 'SA' ]
```

Having a bunch of objects with a single field seems wasteful. However, if you want an array of objects like in your question then, this will do it:

```
var regions = _.map(rawCollection, _.partialRight(_.pick, 'region'));
```

The use of `partialRight` allows abbreviating the code. It is equivalent to:

```
var regions = _.map(rawCollection , function (x) {
   return _.pick(x, 'region');
});
```

Either `map` calls will return:

```
[ { region: 'Europe' }, { region: 'NA' }, { region: 'SA' } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`_.pluck`](http://lodash.com/docs#pluck)

```
   var regions = _.pluck(rawCollection , 'region');
```

Comment: `pick` needs to be called on an object, not a collection

Comment: @Bergi . Thanks for pointing that out. Was actually referring to `_.pluck`.